# Formatear Input text con formato de punto en miles y coma en decimales

Tags: angular, entrada, angular-directivas, component, pipe

Estoy intentando crear una directiva u otro elemento que me permita mostrar formateado un input text como `12.345,67` y que introduzca la coma decimal (,).

**Ejemplos:**

> Mil, formateado debería ser 1.000
>
> Mil con 53 decimales, formateado debería ser 1.000,53

En mis intentos evidentemente al meter la coma como decimal da error.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cf2hz8

Comment: Debe ser necesariamente una directiva? Podría brindarte una solución con pipe.

Comment: No, no tiene porqué ser una directiva. Lo que me gustaba de la directiva es que con un simple texto en cada input se "arreglaba" el problema y así que tuviera poca modificación el proyecto. También lo tenía hecho con un pipe, pero tampoco me acaba de funcionar bien.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p3jc14

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te propongo este pipe, bastante simple de entender y de utilizar también. Pruebalo y me dices como te fue.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

const PADDING = "000000";

@Pipe({ name: "thousandsPipe" })
export class ThousandsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  private DECIMAL_SEPARATOR: string;
  private THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR: string;

  constructor() {
    // TODO Puedes configurar los separadores que prefieras
    this.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = ",";
    this.THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR = ".";
  }

  transform(value: number | string, fractionSize: number = 2): string {
    let [ integer, fraction = "" ] = (value || "").toString()
      .split(this.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR); // Divide entre parte entera y decimal, por la "," en este caso

    fraction = fractionSize > 0
      ? this.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR + (fraction + PADDING).substring(0, fractionSize)
      : "";

    integer = integer.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, this.THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR);

    return integer + fraction;
  }

  parse(value: string, fractionSize: number = 2): string {
    let [ integer, fraction = "" ] = (value || "").split(this.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR);

    integer = integer.replace(new RegExp(this.THOUSANDS_SEPARATOR, "g"), "");

    fraction = parseInt(fraction, 10) > 0 && fractionSize > 0
      ? this.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR + (fraction + PADDING).substring(0, fractionSize)
      : "";

    return integer + fraction;
  }

}
```

Lo usas de la siguiente forma:

```
<p>{{amount | thousandsPipe}} </p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya había visto ese pipe, aunque me gustaba más el mío. El problema es que eso sólo es un pipe  para mostrar un formato, pero también quiero introducir los datos con una coma en el punto decimal.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p3jc14

Comment: Ahora entiendo bien lo que quieres, no habria problema en que llegue con el separador "," solo no deberia ser de tipo number el parametro. No funciona ese stackblitz.

Answer (score -1):

Al final encontré la solución:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tay52r

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input, Output, EventEmitter, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-control-value-accessor',
  template: `
  <input 
    type="text" 
    [(ngModel)]="valueInputText" 
    (focus)="onFocus($event);" 
    (change)="onChange($event)" 
    (blur)="onBlur($event)"
    (mouseup)="$event.preventDefault()"
    (ngModelChange)="onChangeModel($event)"
    (keydown)="onKeydown($event)"
    (paste)="onPaste($event)"
    [disabled]="isDisabled" > 

    <p>Modelo del componente input: {{value}}</p>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => ControlValueAccessorComponent),
        multi: true
    },
]
})
export class ControlValueAccessorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor {
  //@Input('value') value: string = '1.234,56';
  public valueInputText: string;

  @Input('value') value: number;
  @Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
      
  private propagateChange = (_: any) => { };
  private propagateTouch = (_: any) => { };
  public isDisabled: boolean = false;

  // Permite números decimales. El \. es para que ocurra sólo una vez
  //private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+(\,[0-9]*){0,1}$/g);
  private regexNumber: RegExp = new RegExp(/\d$/g);
  //private regexAny: RegExp = new RegExp(/\D$/g);
  //private copyPasteKeys: string = '';
  private copyPasteKeys: Array<string> = ['Control','Shift','c','v','Insert'];
  private copyPastePreviousKey: string;
  private InitialcopyPastePreviousKey: any;

  // Teclas que permito introducir
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Enter','Backspace','Tab','End','Home','ArrowRight','ArrowLeft','Delete',','];
  //private commaCounter: number; // Contador de comas
  
  constructor() {  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.copyPastePreviousKey = '';
    this.InitialcopyPastePreviousKey = setInterval(() => {
      this.copyPastePreviousKey = ''; 
    }, 1000);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.InitialcopyPastePreviousKey) {
      clearInterval(this.InitialcopyPastePreviousKey);
    }
  }

  onFocus(event: any): void {
    console.log('onFocus event.target.value: ', event.target.value);
    console.log('onFocus this.valueInputText: ', this.valueInputText);
    
    if (this.valueInputText == null){
      this.valueInputText = '0,00';
      console.log('inicializado');
    }
    // Elimino todos los puntos ('.') del string
    let regex = /\./g;
    this.valueInputText = this.valueInputText.replace(regex, '');
  }

  onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    console.log('onKeydown', event.key);
    /*
    //console.log('onKeydown event.key: ', event.key);
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) != -1 || String(event.key).match(this.regexNumber) || event.key == ',') {
      if (event.key == ','){
        if (this.commaCounter == undefined) {
          this.commaCounter = 0;
          //console.log('this.commaCounter: ', this.commaCounter);
        }else if (this.commaCounter > 0){
          event.preventDefault();          
          //console.log('onKeydown preventDefault');
        }else {
          this.commaCounter++;
          return;
        }
      }
      //console.log('onKeydown return: ');
      return;
    }else {
      //console.log('onKeydown preventDefault');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    */

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////
 
  console.log('onKeydown event.key: ', event.key);
  
  if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) != -1 || String(event.key).match(this.regexNumber) || event.key == ',') {
    if (event.key == ',') {
      if(this.valueInputText.search(',') >= 0) {
        event.preventDefault();        
      }
    }
    return;
  } else if (this.copyPasteKeys.indexOf(event.key) != -1) { // Control de Copy & Paste
    if (event.key == 'Control' || event.key == 'Shift') {
      this.copyPastePreviousKey = event.key;
    }
    console.log('this.copyPasteKeys.indexOf(event.key) != -1: ', this.copyPasteKeys.indexOf(event.key) != -1);
    console.log('this.copyPastePreviousKey == "Control" || this.copyPastePreviousKey == "Shift": ', this.copyPastePreviousKey == 'Control' || this.copyPastePreviousKey == 'Shift');
    if (this.copyPasteKeys.indexOf(event.key) != -1 && (this.copyPastePreviousKey == 'Control' || this.copyPastePreviousKey == 'Shift')) {
      return;
    }else {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  } else {
    //console.log('onKeydown preventDefault');      
    event.preventDefault();    
  }
}

  onBlur(event: ClipboardEvent): void {
    console.log('onBlur this.valueInputText (antes) ', this.valueInputText);
    // if (this.valueInputText) {
    //   this.commaCounter = this.counterString(this.valueInputText,',');
    // }else {
    //   this.commaCounter = 0;
    // }
    // Elimino todos los puntos ('.') del string
    let regex = /\./g;
    this.valueInputText = this.valueInputText.replace(regex, '');

    this.valueInputText = this.thousandsSeparator(this.valueInputText);
    // console.log('onBlur this.valueInputText (despues): ', this.valueInputText);
    // console.log('onBlur this.parseStringNumber(this.valueInputText): ', this.parseStringNumber(this.valueInputText));
    this.value = this.parseStringNumber(this.valueInputText);
    // console.log('onBlur this.value: ', this.value, typeof(this.value));
    
    this.valueChange.emit(this.value); 
  }
  
  
  private onChange(event : any): void {
    this.propagateChange(this.valueInputText);
    //console.log('onChange this.valueInputText (antes): ', this.valueInputText);
    this.valueInputText = this.thousandsSeparator(this.valueInputText);
    // console.log('onChange this.valueInputText (después): ', this.valueInputText);
    // console.log('onChange this.parseStringNumber(this.valueInputText): ', this.parseStringNumber(this.valueInputText));
    this.value = this.parseStringNumber(this.valueInputText);
    // console.log('onChange this.value: ', this.value, typeof(this.value));
    
    this.valueChange.emit(this.value); 
  }

  onPaste(event: any): void {
        
  }

  /**
   * Allows Angular to update the model (rating).
   * Update the model and changes needed for the view here.
   * @param  {any} value
   * @returns void
   */
  writeValue(value: any): void {
    // console.log('writeValue value: ', value);
    if (value) {
      this.valueInputText = value;
    }
  }
  
  /**
   * Allows Angular to register a function to call when the model (rating) changes.
   * Save the function as a property to call later here.
   * @param  {(_:any)=>void} fn
   * @returns void
   */
  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
      this.propagateChange = fn;      
  }

  /**
   * Allows Angular to register a function to call when the input has been touched.
   * Save the function as a property to call later here.
   * @param  {()=>void} fn
   * @returns void
   */
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
      this.propagateTouch = fn;
  }

  private onChangeModel(value: any) {
    //console.log('onChangeModel value: ', value);
  }

  private onTouch(event : any){
    console.log('onTouch event: ', event);
    this.propagateTouch(event);
    console.log('onTouch this.propagateTouch(event): ', this.propagateTouch(event));
  }
  
  /**
   * Allows Angular to disable the input.
   * @param  {boolean} isDisabled
   * @returns void
   */
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
  }

  /**
   * Cuenta las ocurrencias de un string
   * @param  {string} stringToSearch
   * @param  {string} search
   * @returns number
   */
  counterString (stringToSearch: string, search: string): number{
    console.log('counterString');
    let i: number = 0;
    let counter: number = 0;
    while (i != -1) {
      i = stringToSearch.indexOf(search,i);
      if (i != -1) {
        i++;
        counter++;
      }
    }
    return counter;
  }

  /**
   * Pone los separadores de miles con punto y coma decimal
   * @param  {string} stringNumber
   * @returns string
   */
  public thousandsSeparator (stringNumber: string): string {
    console.log('thousandsSeparator');
    let resultado: string;
    stringNumber = stringNumber.replace(',','.');
    console.log('thousandsSeparator stringNumber: ', stringNumber);
    let flotante: number = parseFloat(stringNumber);
    let flotanteString = flotante.toFixed(2);
    resultado = flotanteString.replace('.', ',');
    console.log('thousandsSeparator flotanteString: ', flotanteString);
    console.log('thousandsSeparator resultado: ', resultado);
  
    let pos = resultado.indexOf(",");
    console.log('thousandsSeparator pos: ', pos);
    // string.substr(<desde>, <longitud>);
    while (pos > 3) {
      resultado = resultado.substr(0, pos-3)+'.'+resultado.substr(pos-3, 3)+resultado.substr(pos);
      pos=pos-3;
    }
    if (resultado == 'NaN') {
      return '0,00';
    }else {
      return resultado;    
    }
  }

  /**
   * Convierte un string con formato 10.000.000,00 a un número 10000000.00
   * @param {string} stringNumber
   * @returns string
   */
  public parseStringNumber (stringNumber: string): number {
    let resultado: string;
    resultado = stringNumber;
    resultado = resultado.replace(/\./g, '');
    resultado = resultado.replace(',', '.');
    return parseFloat(resultado);
  }

  
  
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inputtextcomponent

Comment: Para responder, aunque sea tu propia pregunta, has de seguir [answer] aportando informacion y explicacion de la solucion. Un saludo